# How to get the "mailbox of origin" of email

Tags: outlook, mapi

let's suppose I copy a message from a shared mailbox shared1@contoso.com to a user mailbox user@contoso.com. Is there a way to detect  programmatically that initially the email was created/received in the shared1@contoso.com? Can the property PR_PREDECESSOR_CHANGE_LIST helps here?

Answer (score 0):

If you copy a message between two mailboxes, AFAIK it is treated as a brand new message in the destination mailbox and deletion in the source mailbox. You can try to look ta the `PR_CREATOR_ENTRYID` / `PR_CREATOR_SID` (make sure you open the message in the online mode), but I don't think they will point to the original mailbox.

Comment: Thank you, Dmitry. In other words - no way. ;(

Comment: Yep, pretty much...